# google play services not available due to error 2

Tags: android, android-activity, andengine, google-play-services, banner

I have two activities in my app and i am showing google AdMob banner ad in these activities.
First activity runs fine and it shows banner ad as well but whenever i start second activity it generate the force close error saying these lines randomly
"No resource found error"
"google play services not available due to error 2"
Required this "..." found this "..."
I have double checked the code, it is same in both of the activities but can't solve the problem.
Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: This problem only accrued when you are running your application on Android Emulator .

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same issue today and all I had to do is:

1. Update Google Play Services on the device
2. Open the Play Store at least once.
3. Then I ran my app again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your showing InterstitialAd in second activity which is not supporting in Android API <9 version .

Answer (score 0):

In my case that error occurred because my development phone was recently reformatted and the Google play services was old.. I searched google play services on Google play but unfortunately it doesn't show up on search results so here's what I did to update.

Download or update Google chrome because it will not let you use this app without updated google play services.. Once downloaded or updated open it and it will point you to google play services where you can update it... :)
Problem fixed..  :)

Answer (score 0):

Update Google Play Services on the device  and it will working fine